# How to collect data to List<Object> from Map<Object,Integer> using java Stream API?

Tags: java, collections, stream

I have map `Map<Nominal, Integer>` with objects and their counts:

```
a -> 3
b -> 1
c -> 2
```

And I need to get such a `List<Nominal>` from it:

```
a
a
a
b
c
c
```

How can I do this using the Stream API?

Comment: What is `Nominal`?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri It’s not necessary to know what Nominal is to answer the question.

Comment: ```Nominal``` - it is Enum

Comment: @Bohemian how would you understand what is the type of key then?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri as per the question, the type of the key is Nominal. That’s all you need to know - see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use [`Collections::nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)) to achieve the desired result:

```
private static <T> List<T> transform(Map<? extends T, Integer> map) {
  return map.entrySet().stream()
      .map(entry -> Collections.nCopies(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()))
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/owfgd4)

---

#### Remark

In the demo, I changed the key-type of the `Map` from `Nominal` to `Object` since the definition of `Nominal` was not provided. Changing the key-type, however, does not influence the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stream the entries and use flatMap to generate multiple copies of each key based on the value.

```
List<Nominal> expanded = map.entrySet().stream()
  .flatMap(e -> generate(e::getKey).limit(e.getValue()))
  .collect(toList());
```